# Executing getCollectionNames() with mongo vs mongosh results in different permission results

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

(Im fairly new to mongo)

Im running into a strange mongo permission scenario that i cant seem to find any information on. When I log into my mongo via `mongo` vs `mongosh` and run `db.getCollectionNames()` I get different results.

- When logging in with `mongo` i get a list of collection
- When logging in with `mongosh` i get:

  - `not authorized on db_name to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {}, cursor: {}, nameOnly: true, authorizedCollections: false...`

I also noticed that when logged in via `mongosh` i can run `db.runCommand( { listCollections: 1.0, authorizedCollections: true, nameOnly: true } )` and get collection information back.

My mongoDb/mongo shell is version 5 and `mongosh` version 1.8.0.  Once logged in I have confirmed I am using the same user with the same permissions.

Hopping to get a bit more information about this behavior.